# Why won't start_transaction set the transaction isolation level?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, transactions, mysql-connector-python

The [start_transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-start-transaction.html) method of the MySQLConnection class of `mysql-connector-python` doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
>>> from mysql.connector import connect
>>> conn = connect(user = 'john', unix_socket = '/tmp/mysql.sock', database='db7')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select @@session.tx_isolation")
>>> cur.fetchone()
('REPEATABLE-READ',)
>>> cur.close()
True
>>> conn.start_transaction(isolation_level = 'SERIALIZABLE')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select @@session.tx_isolation")
>>> cur.fetchone()
('REPEATABLE-READ',)
```

The isolation level remains REPEATABLE-READ despite setting the isolation level to 'SERIALIZABLE' in the `start_transaction` call.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the answer to my own question.

This is because

```
select @@session.tx_isolation
```

returns the "session transaction isolation", which actually is not always the current transaction isolation level. If you issue a

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

before a

```
START TRANSACTION
```

the transaction will be SERIALIZABLE, but the @@session.tx_isolation remains the same.

The "session transaction isolation" seems to be a default value for transactions when you don't specify the isolation before starting a transaction.

They say here that it's impossible to find out the current transaction isolation level:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53341

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TRX_ISOLATION_LEVEL
  FROM information_schema.innodb_trx
 WHERE TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID = CONNECTION_ID();
```

This should give you your current transaction's isolation level.  However, unless you `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;` the transaction won't likely appear here until after InnoDB has seen you run at least one query.